# How to validate code if already exist

Tags: php, mysqli

Hi guys I'm New in web developing
I have a problem
I want to validate location code if already exist echo error
how to do this?

This is my codes..
This is correct?..

```
 $lcode = $_POST['locationcode'];
 $ladd  = $_POST['locationadd'];

 $chqry = $mysqli->query("SELECT locationcode FROM table_station");

 if($chqry == $lcode){

  echo "error";
 }

 else{

 $stationadd =  $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO table_station
                          (locationcode,locationaddress)
                  VALUES 
                  (?,?)");

 $stationadd->bind_param('is',$lcode,$ladd);
 $stationadd->execute();
 $stationadd->close();
 $mysqli->close();

echo "<script>alert('station information added');</script>";
}
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE..

Comment: *"This is my codes.. This is correct?"* --- Have you tested it? Do you get any errors? (*other?*)

Comment: Hi @Fred-ii- there's no error 
but the location code still added..

Comment: You need to use this logic `if(mysqli_num_rows($chqry) > 0)` instead of `if($chqry == $lcode)` and maybe adding a `WHERE` clause. I.e.: `WHERE column='".$something."'"`

Comment: @Fred-ii- thank you I got an idea now ...
thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are triying to check the value if it exists you can try ;

```
$lcode = $_POST['locationcode'];
$chqry = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_station WHERE lcode=?");
    $chqry->bind_param("s", $lcode); // you can change the 's' according to type of your data
    $chqry->execute();
    $chqry->store_result(); 
    $row_chqry = $chqry->num_rows;

if($row_chqry  > 0 ) {

$chqry->close(); 
$mysqli->close();
//your error
}
```

That way you can get the number of the rows which includes the posted value. And if number of the rows are greater than 0 you can echo some error..

Comment: Thanks You @ctarimli
This is i want THank you very much..
Sorry for not clearly question haha..
thanks again..

Comment: Not at all. You may want to use `$chqry->close(); $mysqli->close();` in error part, too. I think you have to close your connections if there is an error, like in success. I will update and you will see what ı am trying to tell. @user33607242